# Using apples suggested code isnt excluding files from icloud backup

Tags: objective-c, icloud

I have an app that has been rejected 3 times due to icloud backup issues. Apple have written back to say that I need to use there bit of code to exclude the files from being backed up. However this isnt working and i am at wits end.

Here is the code i've used

```
- (BOOL)downloadFile:(NSString *)fileURI targetFolder:(NSString *)targetFolder targetFilename:(NSString *) targetFilename{
    @try{

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileURI];
        if(![url setResourceValue:@"YES" forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error]){
            NSLog(@"KCDM: Error excluding %@ from backup %@", fileURI, error);
        }else{
            NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

            if ( urlData )
            {
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:targetFolder];
                NSError *error = nil;

                if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]){
                    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
                }

                NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%@", documentsDirectory,targetFolder,targetFilename];


                return [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch(NSException * e){
        NSLog(@"Error download: %@",e);
    }

    return false;
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You try to set `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` for the `http://`-Url you download from the web. That won't work.

You have to set this key-value pair for the actual file that is saved on the device. 
Additionally you are not supposed to set this value to the string `@"YES"`, you must use a NSNumber object representing the boolean value `YES`.

For example:

```
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%@", documentsDirectory,targetFolder,targetFilename];
if ([urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]) {
    // did write correctly
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    if(![fileURL setResourceValue:@YES forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error]){
        NSLog(@"KCDM: Error excluding %@ from backup %@", fileURI, error);
        return NO;
    }
    // could set NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey 
    return YES;
}
// could not write to file
return NO;
```